# Position stacked font awesome icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to create a "vegetarian" icon by stacking fa-circle on fa-square-o. The problem is that the circle is not centrally aligned vertically with respect to the square. I tried using margin/padding/vertical-align css properties but they have no effect whatsoever. my code is:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
<i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x " ></i>
</span>
```

[image]

Comment: your square is double size, your circle is single size, look for a smaller circle or dot and you will be able to make it double sized too, then they should line up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can move it up, by adding a top:

```
.fa-stack-1x {
    top: -1px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! i dont know why padding and margin didnt work.

Comment: Padding can't be negative, but `.fa-stack-1x { margin-top: -1px; }` should work.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the following example you can quickly guess, that the problem with centering the circle is not do to the circles `vertical-align` value, it's `height`, or `top` and `left` position.

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");

.fa-square-o {
  color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
}

.fa-circle {
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
</span>

<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
    <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

The circle just does not fit into the square, because the `font-size` value of the `.fa-stack-2x` class, with a default value of `2em`, is oblivious too small for the circle to fit into the square.

The easiest way to fix this is by increasing the `font-size` value of the icon used as the `fa-stack-2x` element.

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");

.fa-square-o {
    color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    font-size: 2.16em;
}

.fa-circle {
    color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
    <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
</span>

<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
    <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>

<span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
    <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
</span>

<span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
    <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>

<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
    <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
</span>

<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. However why does this occur? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/examples/#stacked

> A method for easily stacking multiple icons. Use the icon-stack class on the parent and icon-stack-base for the bottom icon. You may need to swap `icon` for `fa` depending on the implementation you are using

so try

```
<span class="icon-stack">
<i class="fa-square-0 icon-stack-base"></i>
<i class="fa fa-circle icon-light"></i>
```

If size is a problem you could use the [fa-dot-circle-o](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/dot-circle-o/) then stack a white circle over it, leaving you with just a dot - or use a unicode font with the [middle dot](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b7/index.htm) for the circle, eg unifoundry's unifont.

The standard way to vertically align in css is to set `height` and `line-height`equal to each other, then set `vertical-align: middle`